# Deus Ex - Best gun

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I keep finding all these weapon upgrades. I don't want to put them into a weapon only to throw that weapon away when I find a better one. What should I be putting the upgrades into?

Comment: What is "best" is entirely dependant on how you want to play. But, be aware the game only has a reasonably small number of weapons, so don't be afraid that you're going to find a Pistol +1 and have to throw the current one away, because you won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going for a lethal/stealth approach, try the 10mm pistol. It can be upgraded to ignore armor bonuses, so a headshot on anyone but a boss would be an instakill.

You can get info on any weapon to see it's applied and potential upgrades when it is in your inventory.

Here is a brief list:

- 10mm Pistol - all upgrades + armor piercing
- Shotgun - all upgrades except silencer + double shot
- Machine Pistol & Combat Rifle - all upgrades and lock on bullets
- Rocket launcher - reload speed and thermal lock on.
- Tranquilizer rifle & Crossbow - reload speed only and target leading.
- Sniper Rifle - all upgrades except silencer
- Heavy Rifle - all but silencer, cooling system
- Stun Gun - No upgrades.

Comment: You have Combat Rifle twice, I assume the second instance should be the Heavy Rifle instead?

Comment: Doh! I was thinking heavy, but typed combat!

Comment: you forgot to list a few: the laser rifle, plasma rifle, and peps gun